# Detect if the server is community in discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I use discord.js v12 and I would like to know if the server is a community server. Is there any property on `Guild` I can check for this?

[image]

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jakye mentioned in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708173/detect-if-the-server-is-community-in-discord-js-v12#comment125000672_70708173), you can check your [`guild#features`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=features). The `features` property returns an array of [`Features`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/typedef/Features); if this array [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the string `COMMUNITY`, your guild is a community server.

Here is a helper function:

```js
function isCommunity(guild) {
  return guild.features?.includes('COMMUNITY');
}
```

And you can use it like this for example:

```js
if (isCommunity(message.guild))
  message.channel.send(`${message.guild.name} is a community server`);
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you !