# Check if a text channel within a server is an announcement, role or rule channel (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How do I check if a channel is a community channel within a guild? Examples of a community channel are `announcements` `roles` `rules`. Is there a way to determine whether a channel is used by admins for a special purpose other than general discussion? This question is specific to channels within a server, not servers themselves.

Comment: I am sorry but what is a community channel?? Do you mean as in an announcements channel? Or a forums channel? Please consider being more precise in your question by including images, or consider reading the how to ask a question panel when posting a question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if the server is community in discord.js v12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708173/detect-if-the-server-is-community-in-discord-js-v12)

If not, could you clarify the question? Having trouble with your terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to do this since these channels are defined by users unofficially. What you can do instead is check channel permissions and make assumptions based on those settings. The problem with this is that servers can have some wildly different uses of role permissions, making this less effective. There's also no direct way to check, but here's one way to do it:

```
let isThisACommunityChannel = null;
let {id} = message.guild.defaultRole, // get the ID of defaultRole
let overwrites = message.channel.permissionOverwrites.get(id); // get the permissionOverwrites for that role

// If the overwrites exist and SEND_MESSAGES is set to false, then it's already locked
if (overwrites && overwrites.SEND_MESSAGES === false) {
  // The default role can't message here, so there's a good chance it's a special channel
  communityChannel = true;
} else {
  communityChannel = false;
}
```

Comment: Yes it's a little bit like this but I just want to detect if a channel is a community channel like an announcement channel or a rules channel...

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Since those type of channels aren't really defined by discord, I'm sure there's not a direct way of doing it. You could probably filter by channel permissions. For example, check posting permissions.

Comment: Found a way to do it. Check my answer :)

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean, and it's not a bad idea. So my bot will check differents permission to check it. Thanks !